# Passing Class that runs task to Completable Future SupplyAsync

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

Trying to compare implementations of futures vs completed futures and check if the non blocking nature of completable futures is a better use case for my problem. Having an issue getting my completable impl to work correctly.

```
        Collection<Future<ArrayList<MeterTariffValues>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        List<CompletableFuture<GetSiteMeterTariffValues>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>(); 


        for (Site site : sites) {
            completableFutures.add(
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<GetSiteMeterTariffValues>() {
                    @Override
                    public GetSiteMeterTariffValues get() {
                        return  new GetSiteMeterTariffValues(
                            site.getSite_id(),
                            methaneConversionVal,
                            nitrogenConversionVal,
                            bu_id,
                            region_id,
                            facility_id,
                            status,
                            resource_id,
                            metertype_id,
                            currentCalendarYear,
                            currentFiscalYear,
                            fiscalYearStartMonth,
                            dates,
                            meterMapper,
                            sqlSessionTemplate);
                    }
                }, taskExecutor)
            );
            
            futures.add(
                    taskExecutor.submit(
                            new GetSiteMeterTariffValues(
                                    site.getSite_id(),
                                    methaneConversionVal,
                                    nitrogenConversionVal,
                                    bu_id,
                                    region_id,
                                    facility_id,
                                    status,
                                    resource_id,
                                    metertype_id,
                                    currentCalendarYear,
                                    currentFiscalYear,
                                    fiscalYearStartMonth,
                                    dates,
                                    meterMapper,
                                    sqlSessionTemplate)));
        }
```

The issue with the Completable implementation, is that it wont recognize that GetSiteMeterTariffValues returns a different type after the task is complete.

It returns

```
public ArrayList<MeterTariffValues> call()
```

But task executor is fine with this

```
        for (Future<ArrayList<MeterTariffValues>> future : futures) {

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ArrayList<MeterTariffValues> siteMeterTariffMonthlyValues = future.get();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalMS = end - start;
            total += totalMS;
            meterTariffValues.addAll(siteMeterTariffMonthlyValues);
        }
```

So im wondering how i can do similar the above with completablefutures.

Note:GetSiteMeterTariffValues implements Callable<ArrayList>

Comment: Please clarify _"GetSiteMeterTariffValues returns a different type after the task is complete"_

Comment: I may actually just need to call the call method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` expects a `Supplier` which is the equivalent of `Callable` for `ExecutorService`.

The way you do it currently, you are just providing a `Supplier` that creates a `Callable`, but of course your `Callable` (`GetSiteMeterTariffValues`) is not called.

You just need to make `GetSiteMeterTariffValues` implement `Supplier` and use it directly in `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    new GetSiteMeterTariffValues(
        site.getSite_id(),
        methaneConversionVal,
        nitrogenConversionVal,
        bu_id,
        region_id,
        facility_id,
        status,
        resource_id,
        metertype_id,
        currentCalendarYear,
        currentFiscalYear,
        fiscalYearStartMonth,
        dates,
        meterMapper,
        sqlSessionTemplate),
    taskExecutor)
```

Note that `Supplier` does not allow throwing checked exceptions, so you cannot just use a method reference to `Callable.call()`.